# Python Simulate Keypress

Tags: python

I am currently trying to create a skript that auto motiontracks scenes. And for that I want full control of which features get detected and  how markers are tracked.

**What I want to do:** *Simulate a Keypress in Python Code*

Im not really great when it comes to coding and I dont fully understand how to work with the Documentation. What I have found up to now:

*bpy.types.Window(bpy_struct)* | has the following:

*event_simulate(type, value, unicode='', x=0, y=0, shift=False, ctrl=False, alt=False, oskey=False)*

But Im not sure how to implement it, the following does not work:

```
bpy.types.Window.event_simulate(type = 'RIGHT_ARROW', alt=True)
```

I should be in the right context since I can use lines like:

```
bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()
```

Which works.

Am I on the right track or am I missing something?
Thank you very much! <3